# LuaLatex: create tabularx with multiple direclua

Tags: luatex, environments, tabularx, lua, directlua

I'm using LuaLatex to create a tabular, but it work only if the entire tabular is created inside a single `directlua`.

Why does the former work but not the latter ?

This work

```
\directlua{
    tex.print("\\begin{tabularx}{\\linewidth}{XX}")
    tex.print("a&b \\\\")
    tex.print("\\end{tabularx}")
}
```

This doesn't

```
\directlua{
    tex.print("\\begin{tabularx}{\\linewidth}{XX}")
    tex.print("a&b \\\\")
}
\directlua{
    tex.print("\\end{tabularx}")
}
```

The error message

````
Runaway argument?

‪./main.tex, 7‬
{XX} a&b \\ \directlua { tex.print("\\end{tabularx}") } 
! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.7     \input{data/Attributes.tex}
                                 
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```
````

Comment: tabularx collects the body and so must be able to find the `\end{tabularx}`.

Comment: tabuarx reads ahead to find `\end{tabularx}` to save the table body for multiple trials but it is not there yet. You would see the same with no lua but `\def\xxx{\end{tabularx}}`   `\begin{tabuarx}{\textwidth}...  \xxx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabularx` reads ahead to find `\end{tabularx}` to save the table body for multiple trials but it is not there yet. You would see the same with no lua but

```
\def\xxx{\end{tabularx}} \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}...  \xxx
```

So, you can use multiple `\directlua` but keep the strings on the Lua side, until you have the `\end` ready:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\directlua{
    nextbegin="\\begin{tabularx}{\\linewidth}{XX}"
    nextbody="a&b \\\\"
}
\directlua{
    tex.print(nextbegin)
    tex.print(nextbody)
    tex.print("\\end{tabularx}")
}

  
\end{center}

\end{document}
```